# CHECK: Determine the groups of order $99=3^2 \cdot 11$.

Tags: group-theory

Determine the groups of order $99=3^2 \cdot 11$.

The trivial group of order $99$ is $\mathbb{Z}_{99}$, which is cylic.

By Sylow's theorem, the number of subgroups of order $11$ must divide $99$, and must be congruent to $1$ modulo $11$; the only possibility is that there is a single group of order $11$. Likewise, the number of subgroups of order $9$ must divide $99$ and be congruent to $1$ modulo $3$; the only possibility is that there is a single subgroup of order $9$.

So the group has a single subgroup of order $11$, which must be isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_{11}$ (since that is the only group of order $11$), and a single subgroup of order $9$, which is isomorphic to either $\mathbb{Z}_9$ or to $\mathbb{Z}_3 \times \mathbb{Z}_3$ (since the only groups of order $p^2$, with $p$ prime, are the cyclic group of order $p^2$ and a direct product of two copies of the cyclic group of order $p$).

Moreover, both Sylow subgroups are normal; let $N$ be the $5$-Sylow subgroups, and $M$ be the $3$-Sylow subgroup. Then $N \cap M =\{ 1\}$ since the orders are coprime, and $NM$ is a subgroup (since both $N$ and $M$ are normal. And $$|NM|-\frac{|N||M|}{|N \cap M|}=9 \times 5=99=|G|,$$ so $G=NM$. Since $N$ and $M$ are normal, $nm=mn$ for every $m \in M$ and $n \in N$. So $G \cong N \times M \cong \mathbb{Z}_{11} \times M$. There are two possibilities for $M$, giving you the only two possibilities for $G$.

Note that in both cases you get subgroups of of order $33$; what we don't get in one of the cases is an element of order $33$.

Did I count for all cases?

Comment: $9 \cdot 5 = 99$???

Comment: Have you mixed two problems or something? The group definitely doesn't have any Sylow $5$-subgroups... Everything seems to be in order until that weird statement.